# V-for inside v-for in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to get object items from inside a parent object using a v-for inside another v-for in Vue.js.

Data structure:

```
flights: [
  {
    "airline": "BA",
    "airport": "EBJ",
    "status": {
      "_code": "A",
      "_time": "2018-03-02T14:19:00Z"
    }
  },
  etc....
]

<div v-for="flight in flights">
  <p>{{flight.airline}}</p>
  <p>{{flight.airport}}</p>

  <div v-for="st in flight.status">
    <p>{{st._code}}</p> // should return 'A'
    <p>{{st._time}}</p> // should return '2018-03-02T14:19:00Z'
  </div>
</div>
```

However, neither `st._code` or `st._time` return anything. `st` returns both values ("A" and "2018-03-02T14:19:00Z").

Any idea on how to return the single values inside the `status` object?

Comment: Are you sure that all your objects have `status._code` or `status._time` in them?

Comment: Well, `status` is a flat object as far as I can see. Can't you just use `flight.status._code` and so on?

Comment: I noticed that one entry not had status._time. Will try to wrap the whole thing inside a conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing the expected output is because, of this line:

```
<div v-for="st in flight.status">
```

That means you are expecting vue to iterated throught this:

```
"status": {
  "_code": "A",
  "_time": "2018-03-02T14:19:00Z"
}
```

and the above is an object, not an array ... so unless `status` is an array, it won't work.

If you expect your code to work, try changing your array to this:

```
  flights: [
    {
      "airline": "BA",
      "airport": "EBJ",
      status: [{
        "_code": "A",
        "_time" : "2018-03-02T14:19:00Z"
      }]
    }
  ]
```

working demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/82/

Comment: Ok, I will transform the data on import to have it as an array. Thanks

Comment: @FilipBlaauw Make sure to upvote/accept answer that solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

It *is* possible to use `v-for` on an object, as you're trying to do with `status`, but the syntax is slightly different; in cases where iterating over an object is useful you'll generally want to include the key as well as the value:

```
<div v-for="(val, key) in flight.status">
  <p>{{key}}: {{val}}</p>
</div>
```

would output

```
<p>_code: A</p>
<p>_time: 2018-03-02T14:19:00Z</p>
```

In your case you already know the specific keys you want, so it would be easier to not use `v-for` and instead just use e.g `{{flight.status._code}}`.

Unless there can be more than one "status" per flight, there's no good reason to wrap status in an array.  This will work with your existing data structure:

```
<div v-for="flight in flights">
  <p>{{flight.airline}}</p>
  <p>{{flight.airport}}</p>
  <p>{{flight.status._code}}</p> 
  <p>{{flight.status._time}}</p> 
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. +1 here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/88/